# How to activate keyboard backlights

Tags: msi, keyboard-backlight

I want to know how to activate the keyboard backlights of an msi gt70-2pc laptop. They say [here](http://www.linlap.com/msi_gt70_2pc) that [this](https://github.com/wearefractal/msi-keyboard) works but I just can't figure out exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of the `msi-keyboard` project.

Make sure you have https://nodejs.org installed.

Here are the steps to install the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/stevelacy/msi-keyboard
cd msi-keyboard
npm install
sudo node examples/color.js
```

As an asside, I just released an app for the MSI keyboard: https://github.com/stevelacy/msi-keyboard-gui
The releases contain a pre-built binary for a x64 system.

Comment: +1 to encourage developers to answer more often :)